# What are the plot holes in Naruto?

Tags: naruto

Can someone come up with a list of all the plot holes or contradictions Kishimoto has made in the Naruto Manga?

Comment: This may end up being too wide-ranging/excessively long, and a lot of things may end up being not necessarily contradictions but just not fully explained yet, because the manga isn't done.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if this type of question is suited to be on SE or not. As for the not necessarily contradictions part, I am only looking for clear cut ones where Kishi said one thing in one chapter and then contradicted in another. Not explained situations should not be included.

Comment: Hope someone doesn't ask a similar question with regards to Bleach :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can something like this be considered a soft question?

Comment: @krikara Kishimoto has done some patchy narration once in a while. You will find plenty examples. For instance, Minato showed the Rasengan to Jiraiya and Kakashi, but not the Flying Thunder God. Instead he taught the FTG to 3 minor characters, including 2 *unnamed* characters. All because Kishimoto wanted to setup 5 Kage v/s Madara, and had previously screwed up by deploying the Mizukage far away to protect the Daimyos.

Comment: Also, Minato sealed Yin-Kyuubi within himself, then promptly *died*, and when he was reincarnated, he can already control the Kyuubi's chakra, something which his son achieved at the age of 16, after a lot of struggle. How did Minato suddenly gain control over the Kyuubi in zero time? Was he learning to control the Kyuubi inside the Shinigami's stomach? :o

Comment: @MaskedMan People can gain their Bijuu's power if they willingly cooperate.

Answer (score 4):

Since the story is still continuing, even would-be plot holes can be patched over later. The only real hiccup that comes to mind is an art issue:

In [Chapter 619](http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/98999_naruto-chapter-619/page_5) the four past Hokages are revived with the 4th Hokage's signature coat rocking the flames on bottom.

But in [Chapter 630](http://www.mangainn.com/manga/chapter/104667_naruto-chapter-630/page_20), the 4th Hokage arrives on the battlefield with coat in full flow with missing flames.

[image] [image]

Comment: That is a pretty cool catch. But in response to your plotholes argument, there are some not patchable, for example, Kishi messed up some of Itachi's timeline.

Comment: mashashi got lazy drawing those flames. :D